# JavaFX nullPointer on javaFX Image

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a part of my project of a 2k12 Dice, which should give you a result, based on the random int generator, and should set an Image (javaFX Image class) on a Label with an animal.

The following:

```
public enum Animals {


RABBIT("rabIco.png"), SHEEP("sheepIco.png"), PIG("pigIco.png"), COW("cowIco.png"), HORSE("horIco.png"), WOLF("wolIco.png"), FOX("foxIco.png"), SMALL_DOG("sdoIco.png"), BIG_DOG("bdoIco.png");


private Image image;

Animals(String imgSrc) {
    image = new Image(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(imgSrc));
}
```

The constructor, when initiated by a click, gives me this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1128)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:706)
at sample.Animals.<init>(Animals.java:14)
at sample.Animals.<clinit>(Animals.java:8)
```

The icons are in a res folder marked as a default resource folder.
I copied the icons everywhere, to res, to sample folder, everywhere. Its like a disease spreaded e v e r y w h e r e , and nothing.

NullPointerException.
Image will notload. The button has an Icon loaded via ImageView but that is a workaround and It's not happening on the labels as this is an ImageView.

Comment: `String simpleImageLocation = "/gui/images/icons8_Puzzle_16.png";
    InputStream simpleInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(simpleImageLocation);
    Image simple = new Image(simpleInputStream);`
this how i load an image then i put it in image view try it

Comment: After 700 lines of code I have it... , it was a lower case l not an upper case I.

Comment: Sorry :) However, the solution pointed me deeper into my methos, and there it was. Enum was initiated with an icon name which had a typo a bit deeper.

Comment: okey good for u :)